# looping over several columns to create ggplots

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2

I want to create bar charts for some of the columns in ggplot. In my real data I have many columns, so I want to write a function that will loop over the columns I want.

Here is a simplified example of what I did:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create Vectors
var1 <- c('A','A','B','B')
var2 <- c(1,2,2,1)
var3 <- c('sam','sam','saul','saul')


# Create DataFrame
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

# Print DataFrame
df 

# select only character variables
df2 <- df %>%
 select (var1, var2)

# create bar charts for 1 variable

df2 %>%
  ggplot( aes(var1)) +
  geom_bar( )
```

this creates a correct box chart. Now to create box charts for all the columns selected in df2:

```
# create function for several columns:

bar_plot <- function(data, x_var) {
  ggplot(data, aes({{x_var}})) +
  geom_bar( ) 
}


# for loop to run function on all columns needed

for (i in df2) {
  print(bar_plot(df2,i))
}
```

The function and the for loop create the bar charts, but the x-label is “i” and not the variables name.

What is wrong/missing?

Answer (score 2):

You must adapt the function to have the column names as argument, not the column vectors. The code comments explain how it is made. Then loop over `names(df2)`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

# Create Vectors
var1 <- c('A','A','B','B')
var2 <- c(1,2,2,1)
var3 <- c('sam','sam','saul','saul')

# Create DataFrame
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
# select only character variables
df2 <- df %>%
  select (var1, var2)

bar_plot <- function(data, x_var) {
  # this is needed because one of the variables is numeric
  # but bar plots have a discrete x axis
  if(is.numeric(data[[x_var]]))
    data[[x_var]] <- as.character(data[[x_var]])
  # the variable name must be a symbol for 
  # the curly-curly operator to work
  x_var_vec <- sym(x_var)
  ggplot(data, aes({{x_var_vec}})) +
    geom_bar( ) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = x_var)
}

# for loop to run function on all columns needed

for (i in names(df2)) {
  print(bar_plot(df2, i))
}
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-15</sup>

---

Another, purely `tidyverse` solution is to pass the function the data only and let the function take care of looping through the columns. This is done by reformating the data to long format, split by column name and loop through the groups with `map`.

It complicates the function but it makes the code calling it simpler.

```r
bar_plot2 <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    group_split(name) %>%
    map(\(x) {
      x_var <- x[["name"]][1L]
      g <- ggplot(x, aes(value)) +
        geom_bar() +
        scale_x_discrete(name = x_var)
      print(g)
    })
  invisible(NULL)
}

bar_plot2(df2)
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-15</sup>

Comment: This works great! The only problem is that if I have Na's, it is in the graph also. How can I prevent them from being in the graphs?

Comment: @user3315563 Filter them out after `pivot_longer`. Something like `filter(!is.na(value))`